# Como eliminar el marcador actual en Leaflet Javascript

Tags: javascript, map, leaflet

sucede que tengo un marcador en un mapa de Leaflet el cual me marca bien el punto en el mapa al dar clic sobre el, el problema es que si vuelvo a dar clic me agrega otro marcador es decir quedan dos pero solo quiero que quede el ultimo visible.

asi es como agrego los marcadores al dar clic

```
    var lat = (e.latlng.lat);
    var lng = (e.latlng.lng);

    L.marker([lat, lng]).addTo(mymap)
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la variable del marcador? debería bastar con `L.removeLayer(marcador)` según la [documentación](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#map-removelayer)

Answer (score 0):

No se si sirva pero intenta, reemplaza el siguiente código dentro de la función.

```
marcador? break: 
var marcador = L.marker([lat,lng]);
marcador.addTo(map);
```

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar qué es lo que hace tu código? Y cómo es que está respondiendo a la pregunta.